# Status of Eclipse 4.2 M7

Tags: java, eclipse

On the [download page for Eclipse 4.2M7](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.2M7-201205031800/) the status is an ominous 'red cross' icon, which I presume it to mean that it's not passing unit and/or integration tests (rigth? there's no explanation anywhere that I can see - but it was a nice green 'tick' when I downloaded M6)

I also cannot find any updates anywhere googling for it or on the [Project's page](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/)

Googling around for "Eclipse 4.2" leads nowhere, nor adding "M7" is of any help...

I'm currently using M6 and it looks reasonably stable and polished, but there are a few rough edges (especially in docking views in different areas of the window) which clearly look 'work in progress' and I'd really like to see what the progress may have been.

Does anyone have any info about whether the Milestone build has been abandoned, or maybe it's good to use despite the 'red cross', and/or when another build is expected? or should we just wait for the official release candidate?

Comment: Maybe an Eclipse group/list/etc. would be a more reasonable place to ask this.

Comment: If you need to ask, it is not for you.

Comment: +1 I think it's a fair question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer which may respond to your question here:

> For the past 10 years Eclipse has been built on IBM hardware. To make
>   the build more accessible to others, a few dedicated committers have
>   been migrating the build to eclipse.org hardware. However, 10 years of
>   legacy is not easy to move (hard coded paths, certain assumptions,
>   dedicated test machines, etc…). They are making progress, but not all
>   the test reports are being compiled yet.

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/05/05/eclipse-juno-milestone-7-available-for-download/

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it, appreciated